# Ubuntu touch: PT translation error

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4, translation

Where I can find this string in Launchpad to translate it correctly? In the photo we can see "Introduza SIM o PIN", it must be "Introduza o PIN do SIM". I've checked in Launchpad and it's fine there. I don't know why in the nexus 4 it is wrong?

[image: Error in translation]

This error can be found when you're typing your SIM card code, after booting.

*Where should I download this newer version?*

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Ubuntu Touch is off-topic here as well. 
Errors in development versions of software must be notified to the developers at http://launchpad.net so that developers can track these errors and provide answers themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the download page of Launchpad and download the new translations:

https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu-system-settings/trunk/+pots/ubuntu-system-settings/pt/+export

Furthermore, we normally don't give support on software still in development, so that's as far as it goes, sorry.